# Neural Network regularizer L1 and L2

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow2.0, regularized

I'm doing music genre classification.
I built a file .h5 with my model which is a neural network.
And now I want to use it.
Here is the code to predict the music genre :

```
#%%
import librosa
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

from collections import Counter

SAVED_MODEL_PATH = "modelLast.h5"
SAMPLES_TO_CONSIDER = 22050
DURATION = 30
SAMPLE_PER_TRACK = SAMPLES_TO_CONSIDER * DURATION

#%%
class _Keyword_Spotting_Service:
    """Singleton class for keyword spotting inference with trained models.
    :param model: Trained model
    """

    model = None
_mapping = [
    "blues",
    "classical",
    "country",
    "disco",
    "hiphop",
    "jazz",
    "metal",
    "pop",
    "reggae",
    "rock"
]
_instance = None

def predict(self, file_path, num_mfcc=13, n_fft=2048, hop_length=512):
        """Extract MFCCs from audio file.
        :param file_path (str): Path of audio file
        :param num_mfcc (int): # of coefficients to extract
        :param n_fft (int): Interval we consider to apply STFT. Measured in # of samples
        :param hop_length (int): Sliding window for STFT. Measured in # of samples
        :return MFCCs (ndarray): 2-dim array with MFCC data of shape (# time steps, # coefficients)
        """
        num_segments = 10
        num_samples_per_segment = int(SAMPLE_PER_TRACK / num_segments) # num  of segments
        # load audio file
        signal, sample_rate = librosa.load(file_path)
        
        # a faire
        predicted_indexes = [0] * num_segments
        predicted_mfcc = [0] * num_segments
        for s in range(num_segments):
            start_sample = num_samples_per_segment * s  # s=0 -> 0
            finish_sample = start_sample + num_samples_per_segment  # s=0 -> num_samples_per_segment
            mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(signal[start_sample:finish_sample],
                                        sample_rate,
                                        n_fft=n_fft, n_mfcc=num_mfcc,
                                        hop_length=hop_length)
            MFCCs = mfcc.T
            MFCCs = MFCCs[np.newaxis, ..., np.newaxis]
            
            # get the predicted label
            predictions = self.model.predict(MFCCs)                
            print ("\nPredictions: {}".format(predictions))
            
            predicted_indexes [s] = np.argmax(predictions)
            predicted_mfcc [s] = np.max(predictions)
        
        print("\nIndex list: {}".format(predicted_indexes))
        print("\nIndex list Mfccs : {}".format(predicted_mfcc))
        
       
        #predicted_index = np.bincount(predicted_indexes).argmax()   # Méthode pour avoir l'index qui se répète le plus de fois
        
        # Ajout de précision du code : 
        """
        Nous ressort de la liste les indexs qui se répètent le plus de fois et s'il y a plusieurs doublons
        triplés, compare la valeurs des indexs et choisi l'index à la valeur la plus élevée
        Voir le code python Liste.py pour plus de précision
        """
        
        indices = list(map(lambda x: x[0], Counter(predicted_indexes).most_common()))
        counts = list(map(lambda x: x[1], Counter(predicted_indexes).most_common()))
        
        print("\nIndices présents dans la liste : ", indices)
        print("\nNombre d'apparition des indices : ", counts)
       
        max_indices = [indices[i] for i, x in enumerate(counts) if x == max(counts)]
        result_mcfccs = []

        for idx, id in enumerate(predicted_indexes):
            if id in max_indices:
                result_mcfccs.append(predicted_mfcc[idx])
            
        result = max(result_mcfccs)
        
        print("\n Indice se répétant le plus : ", max_indices)
        print("\nValeur maximale de l'indice se répétant le plus : ",result)
        
        
        indice = predicted_mfcc.index(result)
        print("\nEmplacement de la valeur dans la lsite :",indice)
        F= predicted_indexes.pop(indice)
        print("\nRésultat final : ", F)
        
        predicted_keyword = self._mapping[F]
        
        return predicted_keyword
    
def Keyword_Spotting_Service():
     """Factory function for Keyword_Spotting_Service class.
    :return _Keyword_Spotting_Service._instance (_Keyword_Spotting_Service):
    """

    # ensure an instance is created only the first time the factory function is called
    if _Keyword_Spotting_Service._instance is None:
        _Keyword_Spotting_Service._instance = _Keyword_Spotting_Service()
       _Keyword_Spotting_Service.model = tf.keras.models.load_model(SAVED_MODEL_PATH)
    return _Keyword_Spotting_Service._instance


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # create 2 instances of the keyword spotting service
    kss = Keyword_Spotting_Service()
    kss1 = Keyword_Spotting_Service()

    # check that different instances of the keyword spotting service point back to the same object (singleton)
    assert kss is kss1

# make a prediction
    keyword = kss.predict("discoTrain.wav")                        # Disco
    #keyword = kss.predict("TheRiversGoingWildCUT.mp3")             # Blues
    #keyword = kss.predict("QuantumJazz.mp3")                       # Jazz
    #keyword = kss.predict("QuantumJazzCUT.mp3")                    # Jazz
    #keyword = kss.predict("AbsconseResilience.mp3")                # Metal
    #keyword = kss.predict("Nature.wav")
    #keyword = kss.predict("elvis-presley-jailhouse-rock-music-video.mp3")           # Rock
    #keyword = kss.predict("bob-marley-no-woman-no-cry-official-video.mp3")              # Reggae
    #keyword = kss.predict("alan-jackson-chattahoochee-official-music-videoCUT.mp3")    # Country
    print(keyword)
```

The problem is that it returns me a value error that I've never seen on any forum which is :

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PMI\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 165, in class_and_config_for_serialized_keras_object
raise ValueError('Unknown ' + printable_module_name + ': ' + class_name)

ValueError: Unknown regularizer: L2
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found why I had this error.
It came frome my path variables.
I only needed to add "ffmpeg" to my path variables after I downloaded the folder from internet.
Here is the link : https://ffmpeg.org/download.html
I copied the folder directly to my "C" disc and added the path to my path variables.

Good luck !

Comment: How did you know this is because of "ffmpeg"?
I have the same problem but this solution diddn't help me!

Comment: Hey !
I just looked in my environment variables and I saw that ffmpeg path were not anymore here.
But nothing in my python idle told me to watch in my environment variable.

Maybe you can see if you have the correct version of tensorflow. I know that this library needs to be installed with the correct version to work correctly.

Good luck :)